# How can I turn my Windows or Ubuntu netbook into a wireless router extender?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, netbook

I have a netbook which I'd like to use to extend my wireless router's range. Windows and Ubuntu are installed on the netbook.

This means I need to get to the Internet using my wireless card and share it using the same card.

Are there any open source or freeware solutions that can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you can do this with the same card. You will probably need either an access point to plug into your existing ethernet port or you will need another wireless adapter that would allow you to create an ADHOC network.

Answer (score 1):

With Windows you can share your Ethernet connection by creating an AdHoc wireless network. A true Wi-Fi extender uses WDS, a feature built into the firmware such as DD-WRT, to allow two routers to communicate over the wireless connection and effectively extend the range.

I can't find any information showing that laptop wireless cards are capable of using WDS to become a wi-fi hotspot extender.